# parentSpanId not propagated in spring boot 2.6.x and spring cloud 2021.0.4

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback, spring-cloud-sleuth, distributed-tracing

I have upgraded my project to spring boot 2.6.11 and spring cloud 2021.0.4. After that, the parentId disappeared from the log.

I am using logback to logging purpose. So there is a way to display it?
I added a logging pattern but it didn't change anything:

```
logging.pattern.level=%5p [${spring.application.name:-},%X{X-B3-TraceId:-},%X{X-B3-SpanId:-},%X{X-Span-Export:-}]
```

Comment: What is the parentId . I can not see parentId  in your logger pattern.

Comment: I added it in the pattern but nothing change: logging.pattern.level=%5p [${spring.application.name:-},%X{X-B3-TraceId:-},%X{X-B3-SpanId:-},%X{X-Span-Export:-},%X{X-B3-ParentSpanId:-}]. When a service A call a service B, The parentId in the service B contains the spanId of service A.